# CGPDFScannerCallback -- what does the info parameter point to?

Tags: iphone, pdf, cgpdfdocument

Apple's [CGPDFOperatorTable Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFOperatorTable/Reference/reference.html) says a PDFOperatorCallback should look like this:

```
void MyCGPDFOperatorCallback (
   CGPDFScannerRef scanner,
   void *info
);
```

Parameters

scanner

```
A CGPDFScanner object. Quartz passes the scanner to your callback function. The scanner contains the PDF content stream that has the PDF operator that corresponds to this callback.
```

info

```
A pointer to data passed to the callback.
```

I am confused what data the info will point to.  Is this something I can set somehow?  Or does the scanner set it automatically?  If so, to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `info` parameter that you passed to the `CGPDFScannerCreate` function.